# show that $\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{1}{p \log p} = O(1)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Please my knowledge in this field is very low so could you help me solve this question in analytic number theory.

Comment: So for what I know, this can be solved using the Abel's summation formula

Comment: So for what I know, this can be solved using the Abel's summation formula with the fact that $\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{1}{p} \log \log x + \alpha + O \left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right)$

Answer (score 5):

Use partial summation, or Abel's summation formula, which states that if $f$ is continuous and
\[A(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} a_n,\]
then
\[\sum_{n \leq x} a_n f(n) = f(x) A(x) - \int_{1}^{x} f'(t) A(t) \, dt.\]
Now take
\[f(x) = \frac{1}{x \log x},\]
so that
\[f'(x) = - \frac{\log x + 1}{x^2 (\log x)^2},\]
and
\[a_n = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $n = p$ is a prime,} \\\ 0 & \text{otherwise,} \end{cases}\]
and use the fact that
\[\pi(x) = \sum_{p \leq x} 1 = O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right).\]

Of course, other choices of $f$ and $a_n$ would also work.

Here's some more detail. Using our choice of $f$ and $a_n$, so that $A(x) = \pi(x)$, we get
\[\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p \log p} = \frac{1}{x \log x} \pi(x) + \int_{2}^{x} \frac{\log t + 1}{t^2 (\log t)^2} \pi(t) \, dt.\]
Now as $\pi(x) = O(x/\log x)$, we can just plug this in to get
\[\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p \log p} = O\left(\frac{1}{x \log x} \frac{x}{\log x}\right) + O\left(\int_{2}^{x} \frac{\log t + 1}{t^2 (\log t)^2} \frac{t}{\log t} \, dt\right).\]
The first term is
\[O\left(\frac{1}{(\log x)^2}\right),\]
while the second is
\[O\left(\int_{2}^{x} \frac{1}{t (\log t)^2} \, dt + \int_{2}^{x} \frac{1}{t(\log t)^3} \, dt\right),\]
and by making the substitution $u = \log t$, one finds that
\[\int_{2}^{x} \frac{1}{t (\log t)^2} \, dt = \frac{1}{\log x} - \frac{1}{\log 2},\]
\[\int_{2}^{x} \frac{1}{t (\log t)^3} \, dt = \frac{2}{(\log x)^2} - \frac{2}{(\log 2)^2}.\]
As $1/\log 2$ is a constant, this shows that
\[\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p \log p} = O(1).\]

Comment: Thank you very much. But please can you elaborate the steps more clearly for me? I do not really understand

Answer (score 1):

If we know that $\pi(x+y)-\pi(x)\leq\frac{2y}{\log y}$ then it follows that:

$$ \sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p \log p}\leq \sum_{\alpha=1}^{\left\lceil \log_2 x\right\rceil}\sum_{p\in[2^\alpha,2^{\alpha+1})}\frac{1}{p\log p}\leq \sum_{\alpha=1}^{\left\lceil \log_2 x\right\rceil}\frac{2^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha\log 2\cdot\left( 2^{\alpha}\log 2^{\alpha}\right)} $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p \log p}\leq \frac{2}{\log^2 2}\sum_{\alpha=1}^{\left\lceil \log_2 x\right\rceil}\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\leq\frac{\pi^2}{3\log^2 2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p\log p}=\mathrm{O}(1).
\end{align*}
Using Abel's Summation formula, let $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$ and $f(t)=\frac{1}{\log t}$. Then we have 
\begin{align*}
A(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}a_{n}=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}=\log\log x + \alpha +\mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right)
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
f'(t)= -\frac{1}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p\log p}&=\sum_{n\leq x}a_{n}f(n)=A(x)f(x)-\int_{1}^{x}A(t)f'(t)\; dt \\
&= \frac{\log \log x +\alpha +\mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right)}{\log x}+\int_{1}^{x}\left(\frac{\log \log x +\alpha +\mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right)}{t\left(\log x\right)^2}\right)\; dt\\
&= \frac{\log \log x}{\log x}+\frac{\alpha}{\log x}+\mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{(\log x)^2}\right)+\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\log \log t}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt +\alpha\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt +\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\mathrm{O}\left(1/\log t\right)}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt \\
&= \frac{\log \log x}{\log x}+\frac{\alpha}{\log x}+\mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{(\log x)^2}\right)+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log \log t}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt +\alpha\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt +\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\mathrm{O}\left(1/\log t\right)}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt \\
&= \frac{\log \log x}{\log x}+\frac{\alpha}{\log x}+\mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{(\log x)^2}\right)+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log \log t}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt +\alpha\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt +\mathrm{O}\left(\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t\left(\log t\right)^3}\; dt\right)\\
&= \frac{\log \log x}{\log x}+\frac{\alpha}{\log x}+\mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{(\log x)^2}\right)+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log \log t}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt +\alpha\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt +\mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{\left(\log t\right)^2}\right)\\
&= \frac{\log \log x}{\log x}+\frac{\alpha}{\log x}+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log \log t}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt +\alpha\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt +\mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{\left(\log t\right)^2}\right)
\end{align*}
But
\begin{align*}
\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log \log t}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt = \left(-\frac{\log \log t}{\log t}-\frac{1}{\log t}\right)\Big|_{2}^{x} 
= -\frac{\log \log x}{\log x}+ \frac{\log \log 2}{\log 2} -\frac{1}{\log x}+\frac{1}{\log 2}.
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\alpha\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt &=\alpha\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt -\alpha\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t\left(\log t\right)^2}\; dt \\
&= -\frac{\alpha}{\log t}\Big|_{2}^{\infty}+\frac{\alpha}{\log t}\Big|_{x}^{\infty}\\
&= \frac{\alpha}{\log 2} -\frac{\alpha}{\log x}.
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p\log p}&=\frac{\log \log x}{\log x}+\frac{\alpha}{\log x}-\frac{\log \log x}{\log x}+ \frac{\log \log 2}{\log 2} -\frac{1}{\log x}+\frac{1}{\log 2}+\frac{\alpha}{\log 2} -\frac{\alpha}{\log x} +\mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{\left(\log t\right)^2}\right)\\
&= \frac{\log \log 2}{\log 2} +\frac{1}{\log 2}+\frac{\alpha}{\log 2}  -\frac{1}{\log x}+\mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{\left(\log t\right)^2}\right)\\
&= \mathrm{O}(1),\; \text{as}\; x\rightarrow \infty .
\end{align*}